# Can someone help me create this UI in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout, tkinter-scale

[UI I need to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asNG2.jpg)

This is the UI I require. I have made the left side of the UI. However, I am unable to add the frame on the right. I think my inherent positioning of all elements is wrong and so I am unable to get the right side positions of a frame. Under the message board, I need a frame in which I can insert text that is all. Could someone help me with the code.
My current code is:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import requests

class mainUI:

    def __init__(self, root, username, data):
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry("900x700")
        self.root.title("Auto Login for " + username)

        print(data)

        # creating categories listbox
        Label(self.root, text='Categories', font=('Times 13'), fg="red", padx=20, pady=20).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.categoriesListBox = Listbox(self.root, width=25)
        self.categoriesListBox.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10)
        #adding the categories
        self.categoriesList = data['Categories']
        for item in self.categoriesList:
            self.categoriesListBox.insert(END, item['Name'])

        # binding double click event on categories
        self.categoriesListBox.bind('<Double-1>', self.categorySelect)


        # creating websites listbox
        Label(self.root, text='Websites', font=('Times 13'), fg="red", padx=20, pady=20).grid(row=19, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.wesbitesListBox = Listbox(self.root, width=25)
        self.wesbitesListBox.grid(row=20, column=0, padx=10)

        #creating the messages frame
        Label(self.root, text="Message Board", fg = "red",font=('Times 13'), padx=20, pady=0).grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.messageBoardFrame = Frame(self.root, width=200, height=200, background="white", pady=30).grid(row=1, column=1)
       # self.messageBoardFrame = LabelFrame(text="Message Board")
        Label(self.messageBoardFrame, text="Text").grid(row=1, column=1)



    def categorySelect(self, event):
        self.wesbitesListBox.delete(0,END)
        item = self.categoriesListBox.get('active')
        for name in self.categoriesList:
            if name['Name'] == item:
                websites = name['Websites']
                break
        print(websites)
        for website in websites:
            self.wesbitesListBox.insert(END, website)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('585x515+500+200')

    application = mainUI(root, "Name", {
        'Categories': [{'Name': '31West', 'Websites': ['a','a','a','a']}, {'Name': 'Book Domicile', 'Websites': ['b','b','b','b']},
                       {'Name': 'Crate', 'Websites': []}, {'Name': 'Electrosonic Inc', 'Websites': []},
                       {'Name': 'HostGenius', 'Websites': []}, {'Name': 'Insane Audio', 'Websites': []},
                       {'Name': 'Itsy Bitsy', 'Websites': []}, {'Name': 'Jobs', 'Websites': []},
                       {'Name': 'Kobe Steakhouse', 'Websites': []}, {'Name': 'MIS Computer Corp.', 'Websites': []},
                       {'Name': 'Natrinsic', 'Websites': []}, {'Name': 'Ramshyam', 'Websites': []},
                       {'Name': 'TEST CO', 'Websites': []}, {'Name': 'W-Appliance', 'Websites': []}],
        'isLoggedIn': True}
                         )
    root.mainloop()


    enter code here
```

Comment: Have you consider making left and right frame and then putting your widgets in it? Positioning like that would be much easier in my opinion. What I mean exactly is: 
`left_frame = Frame(root)
left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nswe')`
And then putting categories and websites in this frame, and then creating right frame, but in `column=1`

Comment: I have not considered that. I'm fairly new to Tkinter so I'm not really sure with how things should be done. If you think the code won't take time, would you be able to edit my code to reflect the desired UI? Asking since I think most of the elements needed are provided by my code. Just not sure how to use frames to format it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class mainUI:

    def __init__(self, root, username, data):
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry("900x700")
        self.root.title("Auto Login for " + username)

        print(data)

        master_frame = Frame(self.root)
        master_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

        left_frame = Frame(master_frame)
        left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nswe')

        # creating categories listbox
        categories_label = Label(left_frame, text='Categories', font=('Times 13'), fg="red")
        categories_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

        categories_frame = Frame(left_frame)
        categories_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.categoriesListBox = Listbox(categories_frame, width=25)
        self.categoriesListBox.grid(row=1, column=0)
        # adding the categories
        self.categoriesList = data['Categories']
        for item in self.categoriesList:
            self.categoriesListBox.insert(END, item['Name'])

        # binding double click event on categories
        self.categoriesListBox.bind('<Double-1>', self.categorySelect)

        # creating websites listbox
        websites_label = Label(left_frame, text='Websites', font=('Times 13'), fg="red")
        websites_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.wesbitesListBox = Listbox(left_frame, width=25)
        self.wesbitesListBox.grid(row=3, column=0)

        right_frame = Frame(master_frame)
        right_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nswe')

        # creating the messages frame
        message_label = Label(right_frame, text="Message Board", fg="red", font='Times 13')
        message_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.messageBoardFrame = Frame(right_frame, width=400, height=400, background="white")
        self.messageBoardFrame.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.messageBoardFrame.grid_propagate(False)  # should delete later, it's only to show frame size, with this flag true frame will fit widgets inside it

        # self.messageBoardFrame = LabelFrame(text="Message Board")
        text_label = Label(self.messageBoardFrame, text="Text")
        text_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Grid works not only in window but also inside frames. So inside window you can put something like `master_frame` with `grid(row=0, column=0)`. Then make 2 frames, left and right with grid `(row=0, column=0)` and `(row=0, column=1)`. It won't overlap because master_frame is inside root, left and right inside master_frame. Then it's just that idea repeated.

Thanks to that you can put as many widgets in one of the frames, no matter where left/right/below/over existing ones and it won't affect widgets in other frame, as they will be placed according to parent.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a lot!